# Duplicate permissions in permission sets are deleted when using SFDX deploy

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, permissions, permission-sets, destructivechanges.xml

For example, if I have

```
    <classAccesses>
      <apexClass>APX_someClass</apexClass>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </classAccesses>
```

in my foo.permissionset-meta.xml.

Adding the same permission again, so the meta file now looks like

```
    ...
    <classAccesses>
        <apexClass>APX_someClass</apexClass>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </classAccesses>
    <classAccesses>
        <apexClass>APX_someClass</apexClass>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </classAccesses>
    ...
```

The permission set file is deployed successfully. However, when I retrieve the file from my org, there is no reference of `APX_someClass`. The permission that was present earlier also seems to be deleted.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169048/how-is-permission-set-metadata-deployment-changing-in-summer-17-api-40-0)  is not clear with regards to the above noticed behaviour,

Comment: Wasn't able to reproduce this with `force:source:retrieve` and `force:source:deploy`. How were you deploying this?

Comment: Hi @KrisGoncalves , yes I was using `force:source:deploy`. Faced this issue in my earlier project (API v50.0). 
I tried it now in my current project (API v52.0) and Im not able to reproduce it either. Should I just close the question?

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept your own answer. Never know if someone runs into the same thing so it's always helpful.